# LoadKeyboardLayout() Function does not work in VB 2010

Tags: vb.net, keyboard

I want to change my default keyboard Layout for a installed another Keyboard Layout using my VB application.I googled about this and find Function LoadKeyboardLayout() Function to do that.But Is this support in vb 2010.When I wrote below code and there is no syntax error.But when I run the program  there is an error called "PInvokeStackImbalance was detected... "
How can I solve this in vb 2010.
Here is my code:

```
Private Const KLF_ACTIVATE As Long = &H1
Private Const KLF_NOTELLSHELL As Long = &H80
Private Const KLF_REORDER As Long = &H8
Private Const KLF_REPLACELANG As Long = &H10
Private Const KLF_RESET As Long = &H40000000
Private Const KLF_SETFORPROCESS As Long = &H100
Private Const KLF_SHIFTLOCK As Long = &H10000
Private Const KLF_SUBSTITUTE_OK As Long = &H2
Private Const KLF_UNLOADPREVIOUS As Long = &H4

Private Declare Function LoadKeyboardLayout _
Lib "user32.dll" _
Alias "LoadKeyboardLayoutA" ( _
   ByVal pwszKLID As String, _
   ByVal flags As Long) As Long

'Inside a button click event
   LoadKeyboardLayout("00000409", KLF_ACTIVATE)
```

Can anyone help me...

Comment: <DllImport("user32.dll")> _
Private Shared Function LoadKeyboardLayout(pwszKLID As String, Flags As UInteger) As IntPtr
End Function

Comment: With this function I managed to do it only inside app.But I want to change layout globally.Any ideas...

Comment: This is wrong. Use LoadKeyboardLayoutW instead.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* all you have to do is switch the longs to integers...

```
Private Declare Function LoadKeyboardLayout Lib "user32.dll" _ 
Alias "LoadKeyboardLayoutA" ( ByVal pwszKLID As String, _ 
   ByVal flags As Integer) As Integer
```